# Azure Geo Replication DB and DB Tier

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am wondering if the following thing is possible:

I want to bring down the Azure DB tier when the DB is not in use for e.g. during the night. For which I have a Powershell script which is working fine. 
Problem is I have the Geo Replication on for my DB, which limits my bringing down the DB tier within same Edition. i.e. Premium.

I want to know if it is possible:
 1. Remove the Replication
 2. Bring down the DB tier from Premium to Standard or Vice versa.
 3. Again add the Replication

If I could do this in one powershell script it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. You won't be able to continue syncing to the same DB, so you would have to sync DB again.